# How to benchmark one function in one full application run with google benchmark?

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking, google-benchmark

The application workflow is something like this:

```
init();
while(packet.read()) {
    if (filterpacket(packet)) 
       process(packet); // function to benchmark.
}
```

Over the course of one full application run, I need the measure the time of `process(packet)`. Individually calling `process(packet)` in google benchmark won't work because process would change some internal data structure which will affect the timings of the next `process(packet)` called. It seems also counter-intuitive to make fixtures for each internal state.

How do I do this with google benchmark?

I know I can simply make some ifdefs/flags and make application version that measures the time taken by `process(packet)` but that would defeat the purpose of google benchmark. My expected time of the `process(packet)` is too small, of the order of 200ns.

Comment: IMO not enough data to help. Also `process` is to fast to be reliable measurable by google benchmark (in such cases it is easy to create benchmark which will measure something else), I suspect you need some other more advanced means to measure your performance especially that the network is involved.

Comment: I can mock the packet.read() to read from file for benchmarking purposes. And google benchmark does well for ~100ns function benchmarking. But yes, one needs to be careful not to introduce other variables that can tamper the benchmark with such low numbers

Comment: Take a [look on that](https://youtu.be/NH1Tta7purM).